# How does determining the area of rectangle relate to binomial multiplication?

Tags: polynomials

[image]

So using the strategy to determine the area of the large rectangle I simply did

$10\times10, 10\times2, 10\times4, 2\times4$ to get $168\mathrm{cm}$ total.

The next question goes on to ask how this strategy relates to binomial multiplication.

$14\times12 = 10\times10 + 10\times2 + 10\times4 + 2\times4$

I'm confused as to how this question relates to binomial multiplication because it doesn't look like it can be put in a for such as $(5x+2)(3x-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Start with this...

$10 \times 10 + 10 \times 2 = 10(10 + 2)$

Do the same for the other two terms $10 \times 4 + 2 \times 4$ (pull out common factor).  You should then have a common binomial to factor out leading to 2 binomials multiplied together.

You may be expecting to see a variable like $x$ (based on your last sentence) in your binomials but you won't in this case.  Should just have numbers in each binomial.

Answer (score 0):

Binomial multiplication is really anything that can be written in the form $(a+b)\times(c+d)$. We already know that the area of the rectangle is given by $12\times14$, so you just need to split $12$ into the right $a$ and $b$ and split $14$ into the right $c$ and $d$.